# locking the condition of if block

Tags: if-statement, locking, c#-2.0

I am using .net 2.0.
language:c#
I have situation where I need to lock the condition of IF block.
Given below is the simplified code of what I am trying to achieve.

```
 Public static readyonly object _obj=new object();
 if(
       lock(_obj)
     {
        //if conditition in form of expression
     }
   )
```

Actually the condition of if block is a call to another server. So I need to make it thread safe.
Is the above flow correct? or there is someother way by which I can achieve that? or I have to lock the entire if block

Answer (score 0):

The lock statement is a keyword and not a method.  It does not return anything therefore the above implementation is an incorrect one.  There are some typos in your question as well.

```
public static readonly object _obj = new object();

void Main()
{
    // Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released.
    lock (_obj)
    {
        // Perform "Safe" Work Here
    }
}
```

If you want more information on how a lock works please reference the Microsoft documentation [located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement).